# How to salvage data from failing RAID0 array

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid

I've got two 1.5TB drives in a RAID0 array, one of which is starting to make the signature failure noises. The data on these disks isn't very important but I would like to salvage as much of it as I can.

However, simply copying the files over will get Windows stuck on the files that are in unreadable locations. Since I don't care *that* much I wouldn't mind skipping these files after a set timeout, how would you go about setting up a copy like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like [**TeraCopy**](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php) which can happily skip unreadable files.

> **Error recovery.** In case of copy error, TeraCopy will try several times and in the worse case just skip the file, not terminating the entire transfer.

Comment: oooh. this looks very promising!